# Перенаправление в другую директорию

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте. Нужна небольшая помощь, как сделать такую вещь, а то не совсем получается.

Допустим, в корне сайта есть разные директории, как мне сделать так, чтобы сайт открылся в указанном мною директории. К примеру:

В корне сайта  есть папки:

- folder
- folder2
- folder3

Как сделать, чтобы при наборе адреса, сайта открылся сайт из folder, но в адресной строке чтобы не было адреса типа www.sait.my/folder, а просто www.sait.my

Такой вариант не идёт, кидает на 403-ю ошибку.  *`RewriteBase /folder`*

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде этого

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ua$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ua/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Закомментирование убирали?

А если добавить базу

Comment: Что-то не правильно идёт куча перенаправление на папке примерно так:
http://site.my/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/....

Comment: закомментирование убирали?

а если добавить базу, поправил исходник примера

Comment: Вообще-то, без перенаправления, чтобы адрес не менялся это делается настройками сервера, указывается где лежат файлы сайта с определенным доменным именем, в корне или в подпапке

Answer (score 1):

`403 Forbidden` означает что нет прав на эту папку вообщето.
если бы было чтото другое, то была бы другая ошибка. Включите логгирование всех действий modrewrite и смотрите логи.