# Изменение ссылки в адресной строке

Tags: javascript, css, sql, html5, .htaccess

вопрос заключается в таком действии, видел на каком-то сайте. Вообщем есть к примеру поддомен a.h.ru. Сам сайт понятно h.ru. так вот как сделать так чтобы при заходе на поддомен в адресной строке отображалось h.ru без поддомена

Comment: [Перенаправление в другую директорию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159767/)

Comment: А зачем такая прорва тегов у вопроса, если всё банально решается через .htaccess? Автор, уберите остальные теги.